# App Run on iphone 5 and 5s ios 7 is crash

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a problem: When run on iphone 4s ios 7, it's ok but when run on iphone 5 or 5s (ios7), at first time open app, it's crash but then run again, it runs fine. This is crash report on iphone 5s. Anyone give me any solutions to solve that problem? Thanks much.

```
 Incident Identifier: D617B62C-E6A6-409F-9B95-FD32A5AB1F7E

CrashReporter Key:   8b8144e0a1722250c79237bbcdc82e34009ae173

Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2

Process:             Cloud Stringers [2395]

Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/3152FC6D-0F06-4A83-B127-A60FA8372E9F/Cloud Stringers.app/Cloud Stringers

Identifier:          com.trek2000.cloudstringer

Version:             1.3 (1.3)

Code Type:           ARM (Native)

Parent Process:      launchd [1]


Date/Time:           2013-12-20 20:23:44.469 +0800

OS Version:          iOS 7.0.4 (11B554a)

Report Version:      104


Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Triggered by Thread:  0


Last Exception Backtrace:

(0x2f185e83 0x394e66c7 0x2f0bbd95 0xb374f 0xcd1ff 0x399cb0c3 0x399cb0af 0x399cd9a9 0x2f1505b1 0x2f14ee7d 0x2f0b9471 0x2f0b9253 0x33ded2eb 0x3196e845 0xbede5 0x7dbc0)


Thread 0 Crashed:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x39a961fc 0x39a83000 + 78332

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afda4f 0x39afa000 + 14927

2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x39a47029 0x399fd000 + 303145

3   libc++abi.dylib               0x38e9598b 0x38e95000 + 2443

4   libc++abi.dylib               0x38eae6e3 0x38e95000 + 104163

5   libobjc.A.dylib               0x394e6937 0x394de000 + 35127

6   libc++abi.dylib               0x38eac1b1 0x38e95000 + 94641

7   libc++abi.dylib               0x38eaba05 0x38e95000 + 92677

8   libobjc.A.dylib               0x394e6797 0x394de000 + 34711

9   CoreFoundation                0x2f0bbd91 0x2f0b1000 + 44433

10  Cloud Stringers               0x000b374d 0x79000 + 239437

11  Cloud Stringers               0x000cd1fd 0x79000 + 344573

12  libdispatch.dylib             0x399cb0c1 0x399ca000 + 4289

13  libdispatch.dylib             0x399cb0ad 0x399ca000 + 4269

14  libdispatch.dylib             0x399cd9a5 0x399ca000 + 14757

15  CoreFoundation                0x2f1505ad 0x2f0b1000 + 652717

16  CoreFoundation                0x2f14ee79 0x2f0b1000 + 646777

17  CoreFoundation                0x2f0b946d 0x2f0b1000 + 33901

18  CoreFoundation                0x2f0b924f 0x2f0b1000 + 33359

19  GraphicsServices              0x33ded2e7 0x33de6000 + 29415

20  UIKit                         0x3196e841 0x318ff000 + 456769

21  Cloud Stringers               0x000bede1 0x79000 + 286177

22  Cloud Stringers               0x0007dbbc 0x79000 + 19388


Thread 1:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x39a83838 0x39a83000 + 2104

1   libdispatch.dylib             0x399d20d1 0x399ca000 + 32977

2   libdispatch.dylib             0x399cc61f 0x399ca000 + 9759


Thread 2:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x39a96c7c 0x39a83000 + 81020

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afae07 0x39afa000 + 3591

2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afacc0 0x39afa000 + 3264


Thread 3:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x39a96c7c 0x39a83000 + 81020

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afae07 0x39afa000 + 3591

2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afacc0 0x39afa000 + 3264


Thread 4:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x39a96c7c 0x39a83000 + 81020

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afae07 0x39afa000 + 3591

2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afacc0 0x39afa000 + 3264


Thread 5 name:  AFNetworking

Thread 5:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x39a83a84 0x39a83000 + 2692

1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x39a8387d 0x39a83000 + 2173

2   CoreFoundation                0x2f150555 0x2f0b1000 + 652629

3   CoreFoundation                0x2f14ec75 0x2f0b1000 + 646261

4   CoreFoundation                0x2f0b946d 0x2f0b1000 + 33901

5   CoreFoundation                0x2f0b924f 0x2f0b1000 + 33359

6   Foundation                    0x2faa7693 0x2fa9c000 + 46739

7   Foundation                    0x2faf84d5 0x2fa9c000 + 378069

8   Cloud Stringers               0x000d18f3 0x79000 + 362739

9   Foundation                    0x2fb69c33 0x2fa9c000 + 842803

10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afcc5b 0x39afa000 + 11355

11  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afcbcb 0x39afa000 + 11211

12  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afaccc 0x39afa000 + 3276


Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader

Thread 6:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x39a83a84 0x39a83000 + 2692

1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x39a8387d 0x39a83000 + 2173

2   CoreFoundation                0x2f150555 0x2f0b1000 + 652629

3   CoreFoundation                0x2f14ec75 0x2f0b1000 + 646261

4   CoreFoundation                0x2f0b946d 0x2f0b1000 + 33901

5   CoreFoundation                0x2f0b924f 0x2f0b1000 + 33359

6   Foundation                    0x2faf44bd 0x2fa9c000 + 361661

7   Foundation                    0x2fb69c33 0x2fa9c000 + 842803

8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afcc5b 0x39afa000 + 11355

9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afcbcb 0x39afa000 + 11211

10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afaccc 0x39afa000 + 3276


Thread 7:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x39a96c7c 0x39a83000 + 81020

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afae07 0x39afa000 + 3591

2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afacc0 0x39afa000 + 3264


Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private

Thread 8:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x39a96440 0x39a83000 + 78912

1   CoreFoundation                0x2f154457 0x2f0b1000 + 668759

2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afcc5b 0x39afa000 + 11355

3   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afcbcb 0x39afa000 + 11211

4   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afaccc 0x39afa000 + 3276


Thread 9:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x39a96550 0x39a83000 + 79184

1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x39a074e9 0x399fd000 + 42217

2   Foundation                    0x2fb69345 0x2fa9c000 + 840517

3   Cloud Stringers               0x000b57cf 0x79000 + 247759

4   Foundation                    0x2fb69c33 0x2fa9c000 + 842803

5   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afcc5b 0x39afa000 + 11355

6   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afcbcb 0x39afa000 + 11211

7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x39afaccc 0x39afa000 + 3276


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):

    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00002060

    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3b60a18c      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x00295d74

    r8: 0x15ee6ad0    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x31ef1122

    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x00295d68      lr: 0x39afda53      pc: 0x39a961fc

  cpsr: 0x00000010


Binary Images:

0x79000 - 0x12cfff Cloud Stringers armv7s  <d3c04b1331a93a74ac51ce358ea78fea> /var/mobile/Applications/3152FC6D-0F06-4A83-B127-A60FA8372E9F/Cloud Stringers.app/Cloud Stringers

0x2bef1000 - 0x2bf14fff dyld armv7s  <fd7cb81f388f39cbac4f71338b669c24> /usr/lib/dyld

0x2ddff000 - 0x2de02fff AccessibilitySettingsLoader armv7s  <617a7994f92a30dcbfc3e90ebabe78b0> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader

0x2e015000 - 0x2e116fff AVFoundation armv7s  <759b362f09e53f37a2ec82372a95d1de> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation

0x2e117000 - 0x2e13ffff libAVFAudio.dylib armv7s  <0925efab4dd338e382aa5b10cdbed33f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib

0x2e140000 - 0x2e140fff Accelerate armv7s  <9340338f3cdf347abe4a88c2f59b5b12> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate

0x2e14a000 - 0x2e317fff vImage armv7s  <479b5c4701833284ab587a1d2fdb5627> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage

0x2e318000 - 0x2e3fafff libBLAS.dylib armv7s  <da4fa367557d3028b02458e2cdf6d84d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib

0x2e3fb000 - 0x2e6b6fff libLAPACK.dylib armv7s  <066ea8372dd23f6d89011f9a4a872d6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib

0x2e6b7000 - 0x2e725fff libvDSP.dylib armv7s  <a5dcfe68199839b989c7be120c14ccb4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib

0x2e726000 - 0x2e738fff libvMisc.dylib armv7s  <ea636bbda5ee33119a4e731aed02fa31> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib

0x2e739000 - 0x2e739fff vecLib armv7s  <663aefa25bc5367baa72ca144ac26d18> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib

0x2e73a000 - 0x2e759fff Accounts armv7s  <811f7e5dcd353c57af6d6de859848774> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts

0x2e75b000 - 0x2e7c0fff AddressBook armv7s  <cc733c2c249e3161a9af19a44aeb1577> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook

0x2ea29000 - 0x2ed45fff AudioToolbox armv7s  <f49f28790aa036c08e5573071a7e2870> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox

0x2ed46000 - 0x2ee4bfff CFNetwork armv7s  <36562cff956f38a09956da9218198ccf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork

0x2ee4c000 - 0x2eea7fff CoreAudio armv7s  <34f47ad0c4d530249298888a1217316f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio

0x2eea8000 - 0x2eebefff CoreBluetooth armv7s  <0211d5169d0d3838a9cbb9dd5086a312> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
```

Thanks

Comment: Does `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` get called?

Comment: Need more explanation.

Comment: No chance to solve the problem without symbolicating the crash report. There are few lines that are in your code that might be symbolicated and spread some light on this issue. (e.g. "10  Cloud Stringers               0x000b374d 0x79000 + 239437").

Comment: @KudoCC: Yes, correct

Comment: @MichaelKessler: COuld you please explain that? I don't understand you mean. thanks

Comment: If it crash in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`, you debug and find the line that caused crash, or it is too hard to find according your information...

Comment: why have you not re-symbolicatated the crash log before...?

Answer (score 0):

please debug on 5s or 5s once your applications.

read whats the issue, definitely some thing going wrong in **applicationdidfinishinglunching** method

Follow

http://ios.devtools.me/

Or run once on 64 bit ios 7 simulator which is same as 5s and 5c

you can get the report.